# Background image not positioned correctly

Tags: html, css

Am trying to position my svg image to the corner of the screen. I have tried to add the background-position: top left; property but it didn't work. I have included my code and a picture of how it looks in my browser. I am still trying to figure out what is the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BICFJ.jpg

```
.div1{
    background-image: url(../images/back.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 100vh;
}

<div class='container'>
    <div class='div1'>
        p
    </div>
    <div class='div2'>
        p
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide the SVG image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably, this the image itself, it (svg) itself has the margins, try this, in .div1 with preferable values:

```
.div1 {
    background-image: url(../images/back.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translate(-10px,-10px);
 }
```

i dont know exact values of pixels, you need to change them..

i hope it helped :)

NOTE: this answer can only help if the svg has margins, otherwise refer to other answers

Answer (score 0):

Enter CSS property for "background-origin" with value of border-box which places the image relative to border box and not default padding box.